# C# - RestSharp - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am trying invoke a REST web service using RestSharp.

Following is my code :

```
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate();

        certificate.Import(Properties.Resources.cert, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificate };

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.AddParameter("undefined", $"param={param}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecutePostTaskAsync(request);

        return response;
```

However, I am getting error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I also tried searching about this error but in all of the posts people suggest to use - `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` and `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true`.

I am already using these in my code, still I see the error. Also if I try to fire similar request using Postman it works fine.

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. C# requires the cert to be imported in user store. 
I was missing this part. 
After importing the pfx to the user store, for the first request I was prompted for the allowing the request by OS, subsequent requests worked flawlessly.